# Stop tabbing out of textbox

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I have an userform in Excel. I have put a check on one of the textbox, which will throw an error when any invalid data is input. The check has been put in the in the After Update event. However, I do not want to be tabbed out of the textbox after the error message is throw. How may I achieve that? Please find below code:

```
Private Sub txt_Textboc_After Update()
If CInt(txt_Textboc.Value) > 50 Then
 Msgbox "Invalid Input"
End If
```

What additional code should I put in to avoid tabbing out if the code executes this If block?

Comment: If you're restricting the entries to integers  1-50, why not just use a combobox and For i=1 to 50 combobox.additem i next? Are you limiting the input to numbers or testing for string input?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bring focus back to the TextBox if there is an error.

```
TextBox1.SetFocus
```

That should make you 'untabbed'